# Screen name isn't getting appeared on analytic server in v4 Google analytics

Tags: android

In application we have integrated Google Analytic with the help of `lidGoogleAnalytics.jar` library.

We are able to fetch sessions and events on server but screen name isn't getting appear.

Below code is working, in which we have created one activity, on click of buttons, sending the event and screen names to analytic server.

Device details:

```
version : 4.4.2
```

Comment: For instance creation we are calling  tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

    // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-36642993-10", this);   To track the page we are calling    tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");  Events are getting properly updated , as we calling   tracker.trackEvent(
            "Clicks",  // Category
            "Button",  // Action
            "clicked", // Label
            77);       // Value

Answer (score 0):

For tracking page view, i am using this in my MainActivity

```
private GoogleAnalytics GaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
private Tracker GaTracker = GaInstance.getTracker("YOUR_TRACKER_ID");       
GaTracker.sendView("Main Activity");
GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
```

For events i am using

```
GaTracker.sendEvent("Action Event","Button Category", "Search Button",0L);
GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
```